# C: Better method for rounding down double to int

Tags: c, floating-point-conversion, math.h

My question is; is there a functional difference between rounding a double down to an int via `roundedInt = (int)unRoundedDouble` and `roundedInt = (int)(floor(unRoundedDouble))` ?

I've seen the latter used in code, and thought that maybe it's for safety or functional reasons, but can't figure out what would be handled differently.

Also: the rounded Double will not be too large to fit into an int, that's determined beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are fundamentally different. Cast to `int` will truncate the non-integer part toward `0`. `floor` will do the same, but toward, -infinity.

Example:

```
double d = -1.234;
printf("%d %d\n", (int)d, (int)floor(d));
```

Yields:

```
-1 -2
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution with `floor` works well for negative numbers, the casting version is incorrect mathematically -- if by rounding down you mean the `floor` operation.

So `#floor` always work as the mathematical `floor` operation, the casting behaves the same for positives. However the casting on negatives behaves like the `ceiling` operation.

Comment: Could you explain how it is incorrect, or give a case where it wouldn't work? Thanks! :) (nevermind, I just realized that it would round up negatives.)

Comment: @BigBadWolf casting truncates the decimal part while `floor` calculates the real mathematical floor